# Get all unselected nodes in dynatree

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree

I have implemented dynatree. I can get all selected nodes simply by:

```
$("#tree").dynatree("getSelectedNodes");
```

How can I similarly get all unselected nodes?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#tree')` will give you an array of all the nodes. And your code here will give you an array of selected nodes. You can loop through the main tree nodes array and generate a new array by checking if the node in a particular iteration does not match with selected nodes array.

Comment: yeah that's true, but I was wondering is there any other way? without iterating over the whole list and subtracting it with the selected nodes array? It looks like too much of overhead.